# Relay trouble again

Tags: arduino

I'm having trouble again with a set of relays. It is the small set that only has the two relays on the board. I've tried wiring them every way imaginable and they still won't work properly. The only way they will come on at all, is if I put my 5 VDC to the VCC terminal, and they will not actuate with the outputs from the controller.  I've tried them with two different Arduino Uno's. I'm also not sure which is the proper placement for the jumper. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We also don't know what's going wrong because we have no idea what you're talking about.\

Comment: We need links to products.

Comment: You really think we're supposed to know all about your setup, even if you did post something about it here before!? I'm not going to go digging around to possibly find what you are talking about. Each question needs to stand on its own. As it reads now *it is difficult to tell what is being asked here*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide more details for us to be helpful. I can't tell from your question whether you are working with standalone relays or some relay that are already a part of a PCB.

If it isn't soldered in place, test the relays by energizing the coil and testing for continuity with the ohm setting on your multimeter. To energize the coil, supply a voltage to the primary side and hook up the secondary side to your DC common, aka the ground. If it is a mechanical relay you will hear a click. Typically, relays use A1 and A2 for the primary/secondary sides of the coil and 11, 12, 14, 24, and a few different numbers for different contacts.

All of the pins should be described in the relay's datasheet.